# Iterating over variable number of iterables in Python

Tags: python, recursion, iterator

Case: I need to find out if three combinations of objects will satisfy a rule.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say the rule is satisfied if the a given sequence is in any combination of items that are spit out by a generator function.  The generator handles what items from the pool will pop out in each of its instances and will not always yield the same items/order, so building a list of items and using something like `itertools.combinations` to generate combinations isn't going to work.

Right now I have a function equivalent to:

```
def is_match_found(sequence):

  items1 = items_generator()

  for item1 in items1:
    items2 = items_generator()

    for item2 in items2:
      items3 = items_generator()

      for item3 in items3:
        if sequence in [item1, item2, item3]:
          return True

  return False
```

But I foresee a future where I will need to see if a combination of `n` objects spit out by the generator satisfies a rule.

I feel as if a function with an `n` parameter that implements recursive `for` loops might be a step towards solving this problem, but my brain breaks when I go to try to right an effective one.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you just looking for `itertools.product`, or am I missing something here?

Comment: seems to be the right tool for the job, i'll try it out when i'm in front of a computer. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a permutation of N-many items:

```
def is_match_found(sequence):
    for itemList in itertools.product(list(item_generator()), repeat=N):
        if sequence in itemList:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: The `repeat` parameter to `product` is keyword-only, so this will try to treat `N` as another iterable, which I don't think is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for "a function with an `n` parameter that implements recursive `for` loops", and by "recursive" you actually mean "nested"… then that already exists: [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). In fact, the short description is even:

> cartesian product, equivalent to a nested for-loop

But it doesn't have an `n` parameter; it has an `iterables` parameter, which allows you to specify as many separate iterables to nest as you want. If you just want to nest the same iterable `n` times, you can pass a list of `n` copies of the same iterable… but you can also just use the `repeat` keyword to specify that. As the docs say:

> `product(A, repeat=4)` means the same as `product(A, A, A, A)`.